# Do we have to memorize the binary digits' representations for all kinds of numbers or their is a method to know how to represent each?

Tags: binary, binary-data, digits, digital

For example: octal 3 is 011 in the binary digits, and decimal 3 is 0011.

[image]

So, is there any way to figure them out or this table must be copied and pasted in my memory?

Comment: Try looking for base conversion algorithms.

Comment: Search for “how does binary work” on Youtube/your favorite search engine. That’ll teach you how to convert 0b11 to 3, etc. Binary/octal/hexadecimal are just number systems like decimal, and after some practice converting them using mental arithmetic, you’ll soon memorize them (just like you don’t compute that 4+3=7, you just “know” it).

Comment: Ahmed Fasih: I know how to do the conversions, but i can't perform them mentally so far, like can't devide and collect remainder backward balalbblaa just by head. So looks like i have to memorize them.